# Html Textarea to resize vertically to contain 5000 characters

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I have a Textarea in html with 100% width of its container is there any way I can fix the height of the Textarea to fit 5000 characters without any scrollbar using only Css?

I have set the Css as

```
textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    resize: vertical;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* For IE and modern versions of Chrome */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For Firefox                          */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For Safari                           */
}
```

**Edit:** Ok my width is 100% which makes the textarea fit 100% of the screen size/container 
So if the width of the screen is say 800px and font is 12px I want the height of the textarea to be set such that it accommodates 5000 characters.

Comment: You have no way of knowing how wide 100% is.  For one guy it could be 50 characters, another guy could fit 1000 characters there.  If you knew exactly how wide the element is, then it would be possible to get a rough estimation with this formula:  `5000 / width * line-height`.  You need JS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well limiting characters isn't so complicated since you have the attribute [max length](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp) In textarea tag.

Assuming you will want 5000 characters in your textarea you will use the next code:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="5000">
   Enter text here...
</textarea>
```

So as you can tell I've added **maxlength** attribute inside textarea tag and set it to 5000.

So after you set max length you might just add alternative way in CSS to keep the scrolling out and make height match to 5000 this way:

```
textarea{
 overflow: hidden;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing that sets the visible part of the textbox to fit 5000 characters.  Maxlength doesn't change the dimensions.  Your code right now just uses the rows attribute to set the height; height:auto doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

With just CSS?  I'll answer succintly: No.